# How to fiddle the %time% output in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, time

I am using this batch file to copy a folder to another directory and rename it by date and time. My time format is ??:?? am/pm.

How do I fiddle with the time format in the folder name output? Do I need to fiddle with it? or is this the ultimate? Your opinion counts.

```
@echo off
xcopy "c:\users\...\appdata\local\comodo\dragon\user data\*.*" "c:\users\...\temp\comodo profiles\user data\%date:/=-% %time::=-%\*.*" /s /v /e /c
```

The end result is a folder name like this: 16.07.14 16-18-51.10

Comment: you can't use `:` in directory name. You must use another character like `-` or `_`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a date/time string that has a defined and unchanging format instead of using the locale-defined ones from `%date%` and `%time%` via `wmic`:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined mydate set mydate=%%x
```

It yields something like `20120730203126.530000+120` and you can use that to construct your file names.

Answer (score 0):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%" & set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"

xcopy "c:\users\...\appdata\local\comodo\dragon\user data\*.*" "c:\users\...\temp\comodo profiles\user data\%fullstamp%\*.*" /s /v /e /c
```